# String para Double - Ajuda!

Tags: java

Estou tentando somar uma coluna de um JTable. Alguma sugestão de como fazer?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    double itens = 0;
                    double soma = 0;
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < jtbRacao.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        itens = Double.valueOf((String) jtbRacao.getValueAt(i, 3));
                        soma += itens;
                    }
                    lblPB.setText(String.valueOf(soma));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao calcular Total Produtos: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

#### Stack trace

```
Wed Jul 19 16:33:17 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Jul 19 16:33:20 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Jul 19 16:33:20 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Jul 19 16:33:23 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Jul 19 16:33:23 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3,58"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at VIEW.TelaRacao$7.actionPerformed(TelaRacao.java:313)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Troca a vírgula da string por ponto.

Comment: Erro ao Calcular Total Produtos: 2 >= 2

Comment: Esqueci de avisar que já havia tentado com inteiro e retornou esse erro.

Comment: Não mascare o erro com esse catch, deixa a exceção estourar e cole a pilha de erros aqui.

Comment: tenta fazer: `itens = Double.parseDouble( ((String) jtbRacao.getValueAt(i,3)).replace(",", ".") );`

Comment: Douglas, não deu certo! Creio que não seja um problema relacionado a vírgula, pois tentei calcular mudando a variável para inteiro e também não deu.

Comment: Quando pego a célula especifica me parece que ela retorna um Object. Pode ter alguma relação?

Comment: Pelo erro, pra mim parece culpa da vírgula mesmo. Faz `System.out.println(jtbRacao.getValueAt(i, 3));` e nos diga a saída, pra sabermos o que está sendo retornado aí.

Comment: 3,58 vou postar a imagem da coluna que estou pegando os valores...

Comment: "3,58" não vai converter para Double, mas "3.58" deveria. Pelo que entendi, vc está dizendo que nem "3.58" está convertendo? Execute isso: `System.out.println("Valor convertido: "+Double.parseDouble("3.58"));` Se até esta linha lançar uma Exception, então eu não faço ideia de como resolver seu problema.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 3.58
5.07
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
 at VIEW.TelaRacao$7.actionPerformed(TelaRacao.java:313)

Comment: Alterei os valores da coluna para "3.58" e "5.07" e calculei...veja a resultado aí acima.

Comment: Douglas, descobri...na verdade eram dois erros: o que vc indicou sobre a troca da vírgula pelo ponto e o outro era o getColumnCount q na verdade o correto é getRowCount...deu certo!

Comment: Ótimo, se a resposta de alguém abaixo resolve seu problema, marque ela como aceita; caso contrário, crie uma resposta e marque ela como aceita. :)

Answer (score 3):

Alguns pontos que vi aqui:

1. Na tela, a coluna deve estar mostrando casas decimais com "," ao invés de ".", que é o esperado pelo método `Double.parseDouble()`. Use a classe `java.text.NumberFormat` para converter e formatar valores de e para strings localizadas.
2. No laço `for`, você está indo de 0 até o número de **colunas**, deve ir na verdade até o número de **linhas**.
3. Para somar valores e outras operações que necessitam de precisão, não é bom usar nem `float` nem `double`, por serem pontos flutuantes. É mais interessante usar a classe `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Observando isso, ficaria assim:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    try {
        BigDecimal soma = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        // pega o formato de número para o "locale" atual
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        // varre todas as LINHAS da tabela, coluna 3
        for (int i = 0; i < jtbRacao.getRowCount(); i++) {
            String coluna = jtbRacao.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
            // converte de string para number
            Number valor = nf.parse(coluna);
            // soma com o total atual. BigDecimal sempre retorna uma instância nova, então precisa atualizar a variável
            soma = soma.add(new BigDecimal(valor.toString()));
        }
        // formata a soma para exibir no label
        lblPB.setText(nf.format(soma));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao calcular Total Produtos: " + e.getMessage());
        // não esqueça de escrever a exceção no log...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o seu problema deve ser na conversão de valor String para o Double, 
tenta fazer um replace de virgula para ponto.

Ex:

```
String valor = "9,99"
valor = valor.replace(",", ".");
Double valorDouble = Double.parseDouble(valor);
```

Comment: Felipe, tentei sua sugestão mas infelizmente não deu certo...